# Unable to migrate data from sql server to aurora Mysql DB using AWS data migration service

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am unable migrating data from SQL server to aurora MySQL DB using AWS DMS service. Currently, I have a different number of columns for a particular table in MySQL DB due to which I am unable to transfer data from SQL server to aurora MySQL DB.
Please check the below image for reference.

[image: Required output]

As the picture suggests, I want to transfer data from booking table in SQL server to booking table in aurora Mysql DB having less number of columns. 
Can anyone suggest a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to cope with this directly from AWS without having to change your schema.  But, one option here would be to simply create a table in MySQL which matches the column/type count of the counterpart in SQL Server, i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE booking (bookingID int, bookingVersion int, ...)  -- 7 columns
```

Then, migrate the data from SQL Server to MySQL using the AWS tool.  Finally, just drop the `bookingVersion` column from your MySQL table:

```
ALTER TABLE booking DROP COLUMN bookingVersion;
```

This should work, because all the extra DML steps I suggested can completely be done within MySQL, and don't involve your SQL Server database at all.

Comment: it can be done for one table i have 28 such tables which have nearly half a million records in each which i have to migrate on a daily basis ,so with above solution it will be very difficult to manage .

Comment: Fair enough.  But my answer might be helpful to others who don't have so many tables to migrate so often.  There must be a better AWS way to do this.